# DNS Setup Possible to split ips?

Tags: dns, cname, zone

Here's the situation... Right now, there's a site that's being hosted (DNS is already setup, etc.) Since setting it up, we've actually built it out.  During the process of trying to push it live, we realized that there's the version of PHP that's running on that server is lower than what we need.  Additionally, there's some required PEAR packages that are on dev, but not on production.  What we want to do, until we can locate the guy that's responsible for handing all of this, is host just the website at the dev ip address.  But, we don't want the mail or anything like to be redirected.  I don't know how to do this.  This is just a quick fix for a crappy situation that involves a missing IT department.  Yes. The whole department. Missing...

Here's what the current zone file looks like (names and ips have been changed to protect the innocent...)  We want the site to point to 11.111.11.111 (let's just pretend that's a real IP...)

```
RANDOMAWESOMESITE.COM.  3600    IN  SOA NS57.SOMEKINDOFDOMAINSERVICE.COM.   dns.abcdefghijkl.net (
                2011121401
                28800
                7200
                604800
                3600
                )

; A Records
@   3600    IN  A   99.999.999.999

; CNAME Records
mail    3600    IN  CNAME   ABC.google.com
www 3600    IN  CNAME   @
mobilemail  3600    IN  CNAME   something.somethingsilly.net
pda 3600    IN  CNAME   something.somethingsilly.net
email   3600    IN  CNAME   email.somethingsilly.net
imap    3600    IN  CNAME   imap.somethingsilly.net
pop 3600    IN  CNAME   pop.somethingsilly.net
smtp    3600    IN  CNAME   smtp.somethingsilly.net
ftp 3600    IN  CNAME   @
webmail 3600    IN  CNAME   webmail.somethingsilly.net
e   3600    IN  CNAME   email.somethingsilly.net

; MX Records
@   3600    IN  MX  0   smtp.somethingsilly.net
@   3600    IN  MX  10  mailstore1.somethingsilly.net

; NS Records
@   3600    IN  NS  ns57.SOMEKINDOFDOMAINSERVICE.com
@   3600    IN  NS  ns58.SOMEKINDOFDOMAINSERVICE.com
```

Comment: Probably better asked on http://serverfault.com/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To just fix www.randomwebsite.com Change:

> www 3600    IN  CNAME   @

to

```
www 3600    IN A 11.111.11.111
```

If you need randomwebsite.com to work as well you'll need to change

> @   3600    IN  A   99.999.999.999

to

```
@   3600  IN A 11.111.11.111
```

Don't forget to update the serial number as well

> 2011121401

as of this post date you would want that to be

```
2011122001
```